# 404 error when trying to register serviceWorker

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I get this error when trying to register the service worker:

> Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was gwreceived when fetching the script.

I'm working with ionic and this is what I have in the app.js:

```
   if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js').then(function(registration) {
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
    }).catch(function(err) {
      //registration failed :(
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
  }else {
    console.log('No service-worker on this browser');
  }
```

On the directory I have the service-worker.js file right next to the app.js on the same folder.

Using latest chrome version on ubuntu desktop.

Comment: Check the permissions for the file? Do you have read privileges?

Comment: You should also be aware that a service worker can't be initialised if the page is loaded locally e.g. for testing purposes. An error message can be avoided by testing against this additional condition: (!/^(?:|localhost|127\.0\.0\.1)$/.test(location.hostname))

Comment: @DenisGiffeler "You should also be aware that a service worker can't be initialised if the page is loaded locally e.g. for testing purposes." At this point that's definitely not the case. Service workers can be developed and tested locally, and localhost is an exception to the HTTPS rule.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You mention that you have `service-worker.js` in the same directory as `app.js`, but the URL passed to `.register()` is relative to the HTML document's path. You need to make sure your `service-worker.js` file is in the same directory as the `.html` file corresponding to the page you're on.

Comment: Open angular.json
Find "src/manifest.json",
Add "src/service-worker.js" next to it

Comment: As Jeff said I created a directory called public in the root directory of my react.js application and moved the service-worker.js into that directory and it worked.

Answer (score 12):

The HTML document which is trying to register a service worker and SW.js should be in the same directory.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

These are great replies and it helped with my confusion. I just wanted to add another thing just in case others are running into this problem and are confused as I was.

If you are using a bundler like Webpack, the path needs to be relative to the compiled version.

If your sw.js is in the `/src` folder but the compiled version of your html goes to a `./dist` folder and your path to register the sw.js is `"./sw.js"`, service worker is going to be searching in the dist folder for the sw.js file.

My solution to the problem above for Webpack is to use `copy-webpack-plugin` and send the file over from the src folder to the dist folder.

Answer (score 5):

You just need need to pass the right path to navigator.serviceWorker.register and it doesn't necessarily need to be the same of html file.

For instance, my service-worker.js is in the Scripts folder of my app, thus I needed to pass the path "/Scripts/service-worker.js" on navigator.serviceWorker.register, like:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/Scripts/service-worker.js')
```

Answer (score 4):

service workers and index.html file should be in a common directory.

Comment: In my case, it was in the different directory, calling register with relative url worked. It would be helpful to mention any special conditions that is applicable by your suggestion I guess :)

Answer (score 2):

This Problem is Caused By the **`sw.js` file position in your directory**

Possible Solution -

**Move your `sw.js` file out of any sub folder/directory and put it at the common or public folder.** 
And the error would go away and the Service Worker would get easily registered.

Answer (score -3):

Try to set the source to look in the root directory using a ~

Like this:

```
 navigator.serviceWorker.register('~service-worker.js')
```