# ServiceWorker registration failed with localhost

Tags: javascript, laravel, service-worker

I'm very new to serviceWorker and I don't know what's wrong with my script. On my browser's console it appears:

> ServiceWorker registration failed:  TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.

And this is my script on app.js for registering serviceWorker:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function(registration) {
        // Registration was successful
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
    }, function(err) {
        // registration failed :(
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
});}
```

and the sw.js is in the same directory as the app.js.

Comment: give it a relative path using ./sw.js or just sw.js

Comment: your sw.js return 404, you need to sort out the script path, it's always best to pass absolute path

Answer (score 0):

see [404 error when trying to register serviceWorker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30336685/404-error-when-trying-to-register-serviceworker)

the SW path should be relative to HTML file that is loading your JS file